# jQuery: Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, scala, playframework

I am going through this GitHub project [play-silhouette-slick-seed](https://github.com/sbrunk/play-silhouette-slick-seed) that is an example of [Silhouette](https://www.silhouette.rocks/) (an authentication library for Play Framework in Scala). I want to integrate it in my own project but while running this example project locally, I get the following errors in Chrome console:

```
Refused to load the stylesheet 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Montserrat:400,700|Open+Sans:400,300,600' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

signIn:14 Refused to load the stylesheet 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/1.5.2/css/ionicons.min.css' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

signIn:111 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-ROFVp_6SjJ96CfhCv_AHojQynKmlFmtBaCEXJv7S5Pw='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

signIn:113 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-ROFVp_6SjJ96CfhCv_AHojQynKmlFmtBaCEXJv7S5Pw='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

signIn:115 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-ROFVp_6SjJ96CfhCv_AHojQynKmlFmtBaCEXJv7S5Pw='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

signIn:117 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-ROFVp_6SjJ96CfhCv_AHojQynKmlFmtBaCEXJv7S5Pw='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

signIn:119 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-ROFVp_6SjJ96CfhCv_AHojQynKmlFmtBaCEXJv7S5Pw='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

signIn:121 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-ROFVp_6SjJ96CfhCv_AHojQynKmlFmtBaCEXJv7S5Pw='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

signIn:1 Refused to load the script 'https://clef.io/v3/clef.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

signIn:136 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-Y9Ig29TVi6thv5LkSGm4AJlOdWZ9HjZkdQ4nS0jpB5M='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

signIn:137 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-2yffux8Me_mUR5B9ESFicOYDJXrNC924Qr8m-iNolik='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

jquery-1.7.2.min.js:1 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-j0bVhc2Wj58RJgvcJPevapx5zlVLw6ns6eYzK_hcA04='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
(anonymous function) @ jquery-1.7.2.min.js:1
jquery-1.7.2.min.js:1 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-u0QaYH0by4HvPJu8fIyF61T06TcExJ0dJ8URDvR5mxs='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
(anonymous function) @ jquery-1.7.2.min.js:1
jquery-1.7.2.min.js:1 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-YIbq9-G1c3GTU4biQ5gJZjGatfr3bn3TKuJrLdBMgQI='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
(anonymous function) @ jquery-1.7.2.min.js:1
jquery-1.7.2.min.js:1 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-BK8FE6438-8lVSkJQqZ7JN0EkkJJLHEyA92A5HQgo4M='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
(anonymous function) @ jquery-1.7.2.min.js:1
```

I googled this error and read about [Content Security Policy](http://content-security-policy.com/) that we must follow when writing HTML pages. It says we need to specify trusted sources in page headers to save our site from XSS and other malicious attacks. I am new to Play Framework, I am able to resolve the CDN related error by serving static libraries like `bootstrap.min.css` locally instead of using CDN URLs but I don't know how to fix the inline style error that I am getting in `jquery.min.js`(few last lines of my error).

Can anyone please help me out in resolving this?

Answer (score 4):

You can add exceptions to your security policy by putting a line like this in your `application.conf`:

```
play.filters.headers.contentSecurityPolicy = "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' clef.io jquery.min.js;"
```

The above whitelists inlined Clef and jQuery scripts.

---

Also, have a look at [this configuration](https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette-seed/blob/master/conf/application.conf) which also includes exceptions for Google APIs and CloudFlare:

```
play.filters.headers.contentSecurityPolicy = "default-src 'self'; img-src 'self' fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net *.twimg.com *.googleusercontent.com *.xingassets.com vk.com *.yimg.com secure.gravatar.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' cdnjs.cloudflare.com maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com cdn.jsdelivr.net fonts.googleapis.com; font-src 'self' fonts.gstatic.com fonts.googleapis.com cdnjs.cloudflare.com; script-src 'self' clef.io; connect-src 'self' twitter.com *.xing.com; frame-src clef.io"
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you have to add the css/JS files sources in your playframework project.
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/CorsFilter

Answer (score 0):

With apache:

There is the solution:

To enable inline execution:

Use keyword `'unsafe-inline'`

Or

a hash (`'sha256-o16sCTZRxtPgUgZTyuPtO/h0ljXAzHAc+UugGRl/zuo='`),

Or

a nonce (`'nonce-...'`)

The best choice is using hash.

Hash allow a specific script or style to execute if it matches the hash. Doesn't work for javascript: URIs. For example: `sha256-qznLcsROx4GACP2dm0UCKCzCG+HiZ1guq6ZZDob/Tng=` will allow `alert('Hello, world.');`